# Exclude recurring events from {exp:calendar:events} loop

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Is there a way to exclude recurring events from the `{exp:calendar:events}` tag output? I need to display a maximum of 6 upcoming events but only if they are non-recurring events. Example :

```
{exp:calendar:events
  dynamic="no"
  event_limit="6"
  date_range_start="today"
}

...

{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Looking at the DB tables Calendar uses I see there is a column in the 'exp_calendar_events' table called 'recurs' which could act as a flag (n/y). Is there any easy way within Solspace Calendar to tap into this so I could exclude events with 'recurs' set to 'y' (without trying to recreate the call with the Query Module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword here is **upcoming** events. If you're looking to display entries in a chronological order (such as upcoming events), use `{exp:calendar:cal}`. It's the only tag that can do that kind of accurate ordering.

More detailed on why {exp:calendar:cal} should be used, and how other main Calendar tags work, please refer to this very useful documentation page: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

To remove recurring events from the listing created by {exp:calendar:cal}, you can use the `{if event_recurs}{/if}` conditional: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events//#if_event_recurs

FYI, most of the conditionals listed in {exp:calendar:events} are available for use within the {events}{/events} tag pair inside {exp:calendar:cal}.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that I can use conditionals within the {exp:calendar:cal} tag however in this case I need to output a specific amount of events (using the limit parameter). If I use the {if event_recurs} conditional and say only 3 of the first 6 are not recurring it will only display those 3. So basically I want to filter out recurring events before the tag loop commences (as if the cal tag had a recurs="no" parameter). Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no parameter for this. As a workaround, you could use PHP to create a loop where a value (eg. `$count`) increments (up to 6) each time an event is set to be displayed.

Comment: Didn't think about using a simple PHP variable counter. Thanks for the response.